# My Uk student visa

Tags: visas, uk, study

I am planning to travel to uk to do a 8 month English course , what type of visa should I need and if is a short term visa , will it be up to 6 month or up to 11 month ?

Comment: For clarity what is your nationality and age? As the course is 8 months, a Short Term Study visa would allow you to stay in the U.K. for 11 months https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My uk visa was denied](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130642/my-uk-visa-was-denied)