# My uk visa was denied

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, study

I am 25 year old and my brother is my sponsor.  They refuse me a short term student visa and please I need a help , I want to reply again and I don't know what correction I should do now ... 
Can somebody  explain me please about this reasons for refusal ? :

1. "Given the above, I am not satisfied that you are genuinely seeking entry as a short-term student. Therefore your application is refused under paragraph A57C(ix) of the immigration rules."
2. "You are applying to enter the uk for 8 months and 16 days as short term student. You intend to study General English between 11/02/2019 to 25/10/2019."
3. "I am not satisfied that you have shown that you have a genuine professional or personal relationship with your sponsor."
4. "I am not satisfied of the origin of your brother's funds or how they have been accumulated , your application is refused under paragraph A57C(vi) and (vii) of the Immigration Rules. "
5. "Although you have submitted your travel documents and your sponsor's documents, the documents that you have submitted do not fully evidence your own personal, social or financial circumstances."
6. "You said you are unemployed and submitted a single bank letter that states a balance of 5000£, yet it does demonstrate how this balance has been accumulated and therefore I cannot be satisfied that it will remain for your exclusive use."
7. "Given all of the above and on the balance of probabilities , that you intend to leave the uk at the end of the visit..."

Comment: It is not enough to show money in a bank account. You must also show that it was legitimately obtained, e.g. from working or investments.

Comment: Related questions on here (that addresses visitor visa but nonetheless useful): [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e), [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab), [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking)

Comment: Your last edit deleted all but the last line, probably just an editing accident, I fixed it...

Comment: EUR 5000 is a round number and a glaring red flag. It looks suspicious. Most applicants will supply a few months bank statements (covering multiple pages) to show they transact with the account and the source of the funds is legitimate.

Answer (score 9):

You’ve been refused under A57 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-3-students with a number of points raised as to why you do not qualify. The ECO does not believe you’re a genuine short term study applicant who will not work illegally and/or overstay. If you want to reapply you’ll need to look at each point and the evidence you provided and address the deficiencies. In particular you need to provide evidence of the source of your funds and those of your sponsor. Refer to https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa/documents-you-must-provide for guidance

To answer some of your specific questions regarding documentation:

Q3. If your brother is sponsoring you, provide evidence of the relationship. Eg birth certificates

Q4. Origin of funds (yours and your sponsor’s) - provide bank statements and evidence of where the money came from. Eg pay slips, income tax returns. See [UK Visa Refusal: Provenance of funds/parking](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39153/uk-visa-refusal-provenance-of-funds-parking) and [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)

In a related question [My uk visa was refused](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/130660/my-uk-visa-was-refused) you’ve asked if you should state you are a student. In your first application you said you were unemployed. It’s not a good idea to change information given in an application that was refused when applying again without explaining. If you recently finished your studies and can prove that, then you could say that you are a student who is continuing their education by studying English. If you’ve been employed but don’t now have a job, then your status is unemployed.

Finally some advice - you’re asking a lot of questions that show you do not understand how to compile a solid, credible application. Do not reapply until you have researched and fully understood the requirements and can provide strong supporting evidence.

Comment: Q3. Thank you i will provide it.

Comment: Q4.The problem is I do not have any money in my bank account. My brother is the one who will cover me all the expenses of study, food, accommodation, my expenses, plane tickets ... through his bank account. Would I have to lie that I have so much money in my account knowing that I have nothing and that my brother is the one who will do everything for me? what document my brother need to show?

Comment: In my first application it was a mistake to say that I was unemployed. I finished my university studies two months ago and I have never worked. My brother is the one who financed my studies, he sent me money every semester to pay the classes

Comment: @Annmarie Jar If your brother financed your previous studies he needs to provide evidence of doing that AND where he got the money from (to show that it was legally obtained and belonged to him). He can do this via eg historic bank statements, pay slips etc. If he sent you money effectively by cash rather than through a bank account of other verifiable means you have a problem, as such transfers are virtually impossible to prove. Read all the related questions and the guidance published by UKVI and you’ll see that it’s rekativeky clear what they’re looking for.